# Wifi issues after fresh Ubuntu 14.10 install

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I've recently did a cleain install of Ubuntu 14.10. Unfortunately I'm having network issues:

1. When I try for the first time to connect to a secured Wi-Fi network (EAP/PEAP, MSCHAP), it works. However, disconnecting and connecting again fails - an error appears: "(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7' failed in libnm-glib."
2. Wi-Fi password prompts appear on login screen.

I have no issues with insecure networks - connecting, reconnecting etc. works properly. I expect it is something privilege related, but have no idea what can I do to solve it.

EDIT:
I have checked that I am able to manage connections fully when running nm-connection-editor as root - after adding connections on sudo they work properly, so as long as I connect for the first time with a network on sudo it's OK...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I'm unable to connect to secure wifi directly. The only way is to set it up manually through "Connexions parameters". It was working fluently on 14.04.

Comment: I get this error on VPN and even on WPA Personal if I don't use the "All users may connect to this network" option, so I think my issue is related. Now get this, if I log out and back in again, everything works perfectly, even with wifi configurations that are not permitted for all users. Could someone test if this occurs in their case too? I have the Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 card.